# signature fields beamer class

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to add multiple (two) signature fields to the bottom of the first page of my beamer document. My first page is a `\titlepage`. I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436061/how-to-make-a-signature-feld-in-latex) but it does not work for the beamer class because of an error

```
illegal parameter number in definition of \test, ... \iterate
and \beamer@doitinframe
```

My MWC is:

```
\documentclass[gray]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Presentation}
\author{PersonName}
\date{27/3/2013}
\institute[InstitutionName]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage  
    %% I was inserting the solution here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=toc]{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}  
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame} 

\section{Second Section}
\begin{frame}{Two} 
Content 
\end{frame} 

\section{Third Section}
\begin{frame}{Three} 
Content 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436100/1778537) to your case, to use only two names on signatures. Also, I deleted the date since you have it from `\titlepage`.

Insert the code below on preamble:

```
\newcommand{\doublesignature}[2]{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace{1.5cm}

  \parbox{.48\linewidth}{
  \centering
  \rule{\linewidth}{.7pt}\\
       #1 
    }
    \hfill
  \parbox{.48\linewidth}{
  \centering
  \rule{\linewidth}{.7pt}\\
      #2
    }
  }
}
```

and after `\titlepage` use

```
\doublesignature{First}{Second}
```

Here is the sample:

[image]

You can adjust the size of the boxes and rules if the names are too long.

Try to read and understand the code.